# how to use the else function in python 2.7.9

Tags: python-2.7

Am using python IDE 2.7.9 and am trying to type the else/elif statement and it didn't worked, I tried it so many times the same result FAIL!

Let me just give an example:

```
var1 = 100
if var1:
   print "1 - Got a true expression value"
   print var1
else:
   print "1 - Got a false expression value"
   print var1

var2 = 0
if var2:
   print "2 - Got a true expression value"
   print var2
else:
   print "2 - Got a false expression value"
   print var2

print "Good bye!"
```

Comment: what do you mean *"it didn't worked"*?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
var1 = 100
if var1 == 100:
   print "1 - true"
else:
   print "1 - false"

var2 = 0
if var2 == 100:
   print "2 - true"
else:
   print "2 - false"
```

prints:

```
1 - true
2 - false
```

Your statements in the question are always true because var1 or var2 are defined. You need to query var1 or var2 against a certain value, like 100 in my example to test if a statement is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Your last statement is not quite correct. `if var2` goes into the `else` branch, because `bool(0) == False`. `if var` does *not* test for definition, it coerces the variable to `bool`.